# Como eliminar el fondo de un sprite en Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Tengo un sprite que quiero para ponerlo como un *objeto de ambiente*, sin embargo el fondo de la imagen es blanco (en realidad originalmente era negro, lo modifique ya que crei que seria mas facil eliminar el fondo si este era blanco) , ya use `sprite.set_colorkey( 255,255,255 )` para que los pixeles en 255,255,255 (blanco) sean *"transparentes"*, sin embargo sigue sin funcionar, habra algun otro modo de hacerlo?

**Modificacion**

-Este es el sprite cuyo fondo quiero que sea transparente ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Esta recortada ya que estoy recortando las imagenes del sprite sheet a traves del editor gimp. En otras palabras, la idea es hacer una animacion y esta es una de las imagenes.

-Logre hacer que se aplicara el set_colorkey, lo unico que hice fue no modificar el fondo de la imagen en gimp y aplicar un colorkey 0,0,0, el codigo quedo asi ...

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,500))
ruta_de_carpeta = '../data/sheet_sprites/enviroment/antorcha'

lista_de_imagenes = []
for i in range(1,13): 
    ruta_de_imagen = ruta_de_carpeta + '/' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    print(ruta_de_imagen)
    imagen = pygame.image.load(ruta_de_imagen).convert()
    imagen = pygame.transform.scale(imagen,(100,250))
    imagen.set_colorkey( ( 0,0,0 ) )
    lista_de_imagenes.append(imagen)

salir = False
frames_per_image = 5
current_image = 0
current_frame = 0
fps = pygame.time.Clock()

while not salir:
    print(current_image)
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(lista_de_imagenes[current_image], (100,100))
    if current_frame == frames_per_image:
        current_frame = 0
        current_image += 1
        if current_image > len(lista_de_imagenes) - 1:
            current_image = 0
    else:
        current_frame += 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            salir = True
    pygame.display.update()
    fps.tick(50)

pygame.quit()
```

-El problema con esto es que la imagen tiene varias tonalidades, con lo que el resultado final no queda como se esperaria ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar un ejemplo minimo y verificable en la pregunta por favor? Creo que se la solución pero quiero estar seguro antes de publicar la respuesta.

Comment: Y por que el fondo del sprite (el cual supongo que en realidad es un surface) tiene que ser blanco? Si cargas una imagen, puedes editar la imagen con un editor de imagenes y agregarle la transparencia.

Comment: Si creas el surface dentro del script y vas modificandolo, también deberías poder iniciar con un surface transparente y dibujar cosas en el sin perder esa transparencia.

Comment: @DanteS. ya modifico la pregunta.

Comment: Ya veo... No sería mejor y más fácil hacer el fondo transparente con un editor de imagen y luego guardar dicha imagen como png (ya que jpg no es compatible con la transparencia)? Si o si tiene que ser un archivo jpg? Si o si tiene que ponerse la transparencia dentro del script?

Comment: El problema con set_colorkey es que si una parte de la antorcha es negra, esa parte también se hará transparente...

Comment: set_colorkey no está funcionando por que, como supongo que ya sabes, no todo el fondo es de un negro absoluto (0,0,0). Realmente creo que para esto te conviene más un editor de imagen.

Comment: @DanteS. si, tendre que hacerlo, gracias por las recomendaciones :)

Comment: De nada c: haz otra pregunta si tienes algún problema con cargar una imagen transparente en Pygame.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía el mismo problema, pero lo edité con **GIMP** y quité la capa de la imagen con **selección difusa**.

[image: Edición con GIMP]

[image: Es el resultado]

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).